# How to create a NGRX effect which takes a record from state every 5 seconds if available?

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-entity

I want to create a queue of messages using NGRX which each message added to queue should be displayed for 5 seconds and then removed from state,

- null value should be assigned to currentMessageId after the last message in queue timed out
- message should be taken from queue immediately if `currentMessageId == null`

---

Here is my state:

```
import { EntityState } from '@ngrx/entity';

export interface UiMessage {
  id: string;
  severity: 'info' | 'warn' | 'error' | 'success';
  summary?: string;
  detail: string;
}
export interface MessagesState extends EntityState<UiMessage>{
   currentMessageId: string;
}
```

---

I have already tried this code and it works well if there was always a message in the store:

```
  takeMessageInterval$ = createEffect(() => {
    return timer(0, 5000).pipe(
      map(() => {
        return UiActions.takeNextMessage()
      })
    )
  });
```

but consider this scenario:

- Effect timer started at second 0 while there's no message in store
- A message is added to store at second 1 then message have to wait 4 seconds for time to tick then gets displayed on view

  - I want it to get displayed as fast as possible and get removed after 5 seconds

---

also here is the reducer function:

```
export const messagesReducer = createReducer<MessagesState>(
  initialState,
  on(UiActions.addStateMessage, (current, action) => {
    return messagesAdapter.addOne(action.message, current);
  }),
  on(UiActions.removeStateMessage, (current, action) => {
    return messagesAdapter.removeOne(action.id, current);
  }),
  on(UiActions.takeNextMessage, (current, action) => {
    // remove current message
    if (current.currentMessageId) {
      current = messagesAdapter.removeOne(current.currentMessageId, current);
    }

    // take next message id
    const nextId = current.ids[0] as string;
    current.currentMessageId = nextId;

    return current;
  }),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here could be one approach, assuming there can be only one message displayed at a time:

```js
takeMessageInterval$ = createEffect(
  () => this.actions$.pipe(
    // Intercept when a message has been added
    ofType(UiActions.addStateMessage),
    concatMapTo( // Queue up the messages
      timer(5000).pipe( // Display it for 5 seconds
        endWith(UiActions.takeNextMessage()) // Display the next message and remove the current one
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work as expected if multi messages get added to queue together, only the last one is displayed, i want it to queue the messages and take them one by one. each of them 5 seconds

Comment: Could you elaborate on “multi messages get added”?

Comment: for example, consider this events:
- message A added at second 1
- messages B and C added at second 2
- no messages for 3 minutes
- message D added at minute 3
----- i want each of messages A & B & C to get displayed for 5 seconds and then wait for the last message